# Get output from SyntaxNet as python object, not text

Tags: python, nlp, syntaxnet

After executing some of an example syntaxnet scripts(like `parse.sh`) I receive output in *text-conll* format. My goal is to take some features and proceed them to next network. One possible choice is to parse text output with something like `nltk.corpus.reader.ConllCorpusReader` to a python object. But for me interesting 
is:

It is possible with some code modification to get from SyntaxNet not text, but Python object related to parsed results?

I've found that in `parser_eval.py` on lines 133-138 syntaxnet fetched already text version of results.

```
while True:
    tf_eval_epochs, tf_eval_metrics, tf_documents = sess.run([
        parser.evaluation['epochs'],
        parser.evaluation['eval_metrics'],
        parser.evaluation['documents'],
    ])
```

But I cannot locate the place from what object this text was generated and how.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, and from what I know all involve parsing the output of SyntaxNet, and load it into NLTK objects. I wrote a simple post on my blog, exemplifying it:

http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/03/25/syntaxnet/

Comment: Hi, David,
Yes I know that this is possible to parse output by some external script. But the question was is it possible to receive result directly from syntaxnet as python object.

Comment: I've never investigated that, I guess you have to play around directly with SyntaxNet implementation in Tensorflow. Another alternative is to have SyntaxNet working as a daemon, I don't know if that is possible, but I suspect this might be the path to go: https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/